# Excel Extreme Average Values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: fig: 1 Excel table depicting extreme percentages values calculated as averages]

I have encountered this error multiple times. What is even more out of place that it does not do it for the E column only for the other columns, and as I am showing you in the picture I know and have written the formula for average, median and standard deviation correctly.

Can anyone take a shot on why this is happening, this is the first time I have encountered this error. I have excel 2016.

Comment: You have the results formatted as percents, but spot checking some of the calculations, they look pretty close.  Just correct the cell format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psychic debugging, since we can't see the formulas:

- Your "percent" columns are actually numbers, that is, you've calculated the proportion manually (i.e. using a formula, not the percentage formatter) and multiplied by 100 to get something that looks like a percentage
- The row titled "Average" is looking at the numeric values of the above cells, takes their average, and *formats the result as a percentage* because of the cell's formatting

Excel's percentage formatter turns a decimal proportion like `0.349` into a percentage-looking thing like `34.9%` at display time. Cell B13's actual numeric value is 88.2625, but because its formatting is set to display as a percentage, it appears to be multiplied by 100. Cell E13 is simply not set to display as a percentage.

To change the cells' formatting, select them and pick the desired format from the predefined format ("Number Format") box, which looks like this for me in Excel 2013:

[image: the Number Format dropdown]

You want "Number."

Comment: I've just noticed it. I tested some other formulas it is automatically setting all my values to percentages from numbers. Luckily, I have changed it back